# Geoman in leaflet, how to disable a click on a polygon?

Tags: leaflet, polygon, disabled-control, leaflet-geoman

How can I remove a click on a polygon. I dont want the mouse to switch to 'clickable mode' when hovering over a polygon.

Why do I need this? There's another layer that (should come) on top of the polygon but since the polygon is clickable you cant click the layer that I (tried) to place on top.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdh2w6qs/)

```
map.pm.disableClick?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Leaflet option `interactive: false` to disable all interactions on the layer:

```
L.geoJSON(geojson,{interactive:false}).addTo(map);
```